# One function with varying return types ... possible with Generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a few procedures, for simplicity sake, look like the following:

```
public string FetchValueAsString(string key)
public int FetchValueAsInteger(string key)
public bool FetchValueAsBoolean(string key)
public DateTime FetchValueAsDateTime(string key)
```

I know I could just have one method that returns and object type and just do a conversion, but  I'm wondering if there is a way I can just have one method called, and somehow use generics to determine the return value ... possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static T FetchValue<T>(string key)
{
    string value;  
    // logic to set value here  
    // ...  
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're writing code in C#. If you are then you could do what your talking about like this:

```
public T FetchValueAsType<T>(string key)
```

You would then call the version like this:

```
FetchValueAsType<int>(key);
```

That being said the the `System.Convert` class provided by the framework works just as well and has similar syntax. You can find the msdn article about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but without knowing the method's implementation, it's hard to say whether there is something to be gained, or if it's truly/easily implementable as a generic.

At any rate:

```
public T FetchValue<T>(string key)
```

would be what you're looking to do.